# any divisor of a projective non-singular irreducible curve is equivalent to an effective divisor minus a multiple of a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Here is a problem I need help getting started with. I am brand new to algebraic geometry.

Let $C$ be a projective non-singular irreducible curve of genus $g$. Let $P_0\in C$. Prove
that any divisor $D \in Div(C)$ is linearly equivalent to a divisor of the form $D_0 - nP_0$,
where $D_0\ge 0$ has degree $g$. Of course, $n=g-\deg D$. Would $D_0$ have to be canonical?

I am given the Riemann-Roch Theorem but I don't know how to connect this question to the dimensions of the Riemann-Roch spaces.

What theorems should I be thinking about? Thanks.

Comment: Actually I think I got it. I learned that a divisor is equivalent to an effective one if and only if the RR space of the divisor has positive dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $D'=D+(g-deg(D))P_0$ so the problem is to show that $D'$ is equivalente to a effective divisor, note that $deg(D')=g$ by Riemann-Roch theorem we have
$$
\dim L(D')\geq 1
$$

take $f\in L(D')$ so by definition $D_0=div(f)+D'\geq 0$ and $D_0$ is equivalent to $D'$.

rmk$_1$: $L(A)=\{f\in \mathcal{M}(X):\textrm{ }ord_p(f)\geq A(p)\}$, and $div(f)=\sum_p ord_p(f)p$ is the divisor associated to a meromorphic function.

rmk$_2$: Of course that $deg(D_0)=g$ because the $deg(div(f))=0$.

rmk$_3$: $X$ just need to be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$.

Comment: thanks. exactly what I had in mind